# Actualizar datos de una Spreadsheet - App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy haciendo una transferencia de datos de varias spreadsheets a una sola, lo que hago es transferir los últimos datos de determinadas columnas a la spreadsheet maestra y también los inserto en la ultima fila disponible de determinadas columnas, de momento, inserto todos los datos pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer que examine la spreadsheet maestra para que si ya existen esos datos no los elimine sino que lo actualice. El script que tengo es el siguiente...

```
      function  Gas10(){  
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); 
      var ssh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");


    var lastRow1 = ssh1.getLastRow();
    var gtRange1 = ssh1.getRange("C"+(lastRow1)+":K"+(lastRow1)).getValues();
    var gtRange2= ssh1.getRange("A" + (lastRow1)).getValue();

    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var ssh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Hoja 2");
    var lastRow2 = ssh2.getLastRow() + 1;
    var setRange1 = ssh2.getRange(lastRow2, 4, gtRange1.length, gtRange1[0].length).setValues(gtRange1);
    var setRange2 = ssh2.getRange(lastRow2, 3).setValue(gtRange2);            

}
```

Como vuelvo a repetir, necesito saber como puedo hacer que a la hora de traer un dato lo inserte (que ya hace eso), pero que lo actualice si ya existe. 
Esta pregunta la volvi a publicar pero en el servidor en Ingles. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168589/update-data-from-a-spreadsheet-apps-script).

**Edit**

[Este](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAByiML5b11KviDZ3tXNCPZHOTVJT6XlybAL4F_nxWQ/edit#gid=0) es un ejemplo que realice para que se pudiera entender mejor la pregunta, en el cual tengo 2 hojas y de la hoja 1 copio el ultimo dato de un determinado rango y los pego en la hoja 2 en la ultima fila disponible y lo que intento hacer es que si el Nombre, Num y Proyecto son ya estan en la hoja 2, actualice el ID. En el ejemplo lo entenderán mejor.

Comment: Sería conveniente que empataras la narrativa con el código. En específico me refiero a que en la narrativa mencionas "spreadsheet maestra" pero en el código no hay ninguna indicación de cuál es la "spreadsheet maestra" así que se esta dejando a la interpretación del lector. Si bien el script no es muy complejo y seguramente el lector no se va a equivocar, es mejor como te lo menciono sobre todo pensando en que luego harás cosas mas complejas. Por otro lado no me queda claro a que te refieres con "si ya existen esos datos no los elimine sino que lo actualice"

Comment: @Rubén Mas o menos me refiero a que yo copio los datos de una spreadsheet a otra, pero si ya hay un dato igual al que estoy a punto de copiar en la otra hoja, solo lo actualice, voy a editar la pregunta con un ejemplo que realice para que se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: Me parece que aún le falta mejorar a la redacción de la pregunta, aún así veo que lo que necesitas es tomar como array unidimencional los valores enviar y compararlos fila por fila con las filas de la hoja de destino. Lo que no tengo idea de es en la parte de  "actualice el ID" ¿Quieres un nuevo ID? Si fuera así lo más sencillo es agrega el rango y elimina los duplicados más antiguos.

Comment: P.D. Veo que el en foro en inglés ya te han dado dos respuestas. Luego reviso si has agregado algún comentario a las mismas.

Comment: @Rubén Gracias por tu consejo, si me sirvió tu consejo cuando le intente explicar a JSmith que me proporciono su ayuda, ahora que ya tengo una respuesta, ¿La pongo como respuesta en este post o indico que en el servidor en ingles esta la respuesta?

Comment: Lo mejor es que compartas aquí la respuesta que conseguiste en otro lugar. No olvides incluir el enlace.

Answer (score -1):

buen día. 
Soy muy lento para programar, alguien tiene un Script que actualice una hoja de calculo y que despues lo pueda progrmar para que se haga cada X tiempo .. Gracias por la ayuda.